# Deploy c# app as html5 only

Tags: c#, firefox, firefox-os

Due to the recent Firefox OS marketplace... is there a way to implement or export C# applications to html5 so that it runs on Firefox OS as a service or it is just an OS only to accept services from the web?

I readed the app can be offline.... so that's my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the C# code is compiled and use its virtual machine and HTML5 is interpreted by web browsers. The whole idea with Firefox OS is to get rid of the constraint of having to use different languages in combination with html5, on different devices ie. Obj-C, C#, Java to access native functionality (different when developing for different platforms).

To interpret HTML5 code, internet connection is not needed, HTML code can be run locally on device as long as the code is on the device.

Comment: i know... but they said the app's can be offline, so i was guessing if that where possible.

Comment: edited to answer your connectivity question.